# Решить задачу матлаб без циклов

Tags: циклы, матрицы, matlab

Как исключить цикл из этого кода? Если с одномерными более менее разобрался, то здесь чего то не могу

```
x=-5:5;
y=-5:5;
for i=1:11
    for j=1:11
    z(i,j) = (x(i)^2+y(j)^2)*sin(x(i)+y(j))
    end
end
```

Comment: Что должен делать код? И чем вас не устраивают циклы?

Comment: Постройте график функции с помощью surf, mesh и plot3.
  = (^2 + ^2)( + )  ∈ [−5, 5]  ∈ [−5, 5]
Меня устраивают , препода не устраивают.

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать функцию `meshgrid` для создания матриц `X` и `Y` из векторов `x` и `y`, затем применить формулу ко всей матрице.
Можно использовать функцию `repmat` для создания матриц, дублирующих векторы `x` и `y` в нужных размерах, затем выполнить операции над этими матрицами.

Answer (score 0):

Если у Вас относительно новая версия Матлаба, то, кроме meshgrid, для вычисления сумм можно использовать сложение вектор-строки и вектор-столбца.

```
z=(x.^2+(y').^2).*sin(x+y');
```